# Using django-filter with django-tables2, how do I annotate a queryset?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-filter, django-tables2

I am using django-filter and django-tables2 to pull data from a SQLite3 database.  The database has 15+ fields of sales order information were they may be multiple lines (Line field) per sales order.  I would like to render a table that does the equivalent of 'Group By' sales order and sum the ExtAmount field.  I know I should use the annotate function but I am unsure where to implement this with django-filter/django-tables2.

In SQL I used the below to get what I need:

```
SELECT SalesOrder, Customer, Count(Line) AS Lines, Round(Sum(ExtAmount), 2) AS Amount FROM backlog_backlogData GROUP BY SalesOrder Order By Sum(ExtAmount) DESC limit 100
```

As of now, the view renders the three fields from tables.py but without grouping SalesOrder. Which is great, but I can't seem to find traction of where I need to annotate.  I've read through the docs and searched through other questions and I just can't seem to understand how to use django-filter/django-table2.  The only place I have found 'annotate' referenced in the django-filter docs is with the ModelMultipleChoiceFilter filter reference. Any help would be great!

```
#models.py

from django.db import models

class backlogData(models.Model):
    Shipto = models.IntegerField()
    Customer = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    City = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    ST =  models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    GLCo =  models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Parent = models.IntegerField()
    SalesOrder = models.IntegerField()
    CustomerPO =  models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    OrderTyp =  models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Line = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=1)
    ItemNumber = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    QtyOrdered = models.IntegerField()
    ExtAmount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    Truck = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    Stop = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    ShipClass = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)


#tables.py

import django_tables2 as tables
from .models import backlogData

class BacklogTable(tables.Table):

    class Meta:
        model = backlogData
        template_name = 'django_tables2/table.html'
        attrs = {'class': 'table is-fullwidth has-text-centered'}
        fields = ('GLCo','Customer','Truck')


#filters.py

import django_filters
from .models import backlogData 

class BacklogListFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        model = backlogData
        fields = ['GLCo','Truck'] #used to filter after GET


#views.py

from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.db.models.query_utils import Q
from django_tables2 import RequestConfig
from django_filters.views import FilterView

from .utils import PagedFilteredTableView
from .models import backlogData
from .tables import BacklogTable
from .filters import BacklogListFilter

class BacklogListView(FilterView):
    model = backlogData
    template_name = 'backlog/index.html'
    filter_class = BacklogListFilter

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BacklogListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        filter = BacklogListFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=self.get_queryset())
        table = BacklogTable(filter.qs)
        RequestConfig(self.request).configure(table)
        context['filter'] = table
        context['table'] = table
        return context
```

Comment: Life is so much easier when you don't use blackboxes

Answer (score 0):

You can add your annotations to the queryset passed to `BacklogTable`:

```
table = BacklogTable(filter.qs.annotate(...))
```

Documentation on how to use [`.annotate()` in django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#annotate). You can use the name of the annotation (by supplying them as keyword arguments to `.annotate()`) as column names in django-tables2.